# add number each day

Tags: jquery, date, count

I don't know if this is possible with jquery. Can you detect the current date? And if for each day passed the specific date it adds 1.

So day 0= 04/02/2012

`<h1>0</h1>`

day 1= 05/02/2012

`<h1>1</h1>`

day 2= 06/02/2012

`<h1>2</h1>`

As a way to counting how long the day the website has been active. Or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to know if it's a different day, something as simple as this would work:

```
var DayDiff = function (start) {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    start = new Date(start).getTime();

    return Math.floor((now - start)/ 86400000);
};

document.write(DayDiff('2012-02-01')); // Today is 2/3, this would print "2"
```

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/zfBrv/

Comment: Fantastic, that is so simple.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has the [Date Object](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp)